# PHP array each elements to each

Tags: php, arrays

I have `n` arrays (for example 2 arrays):

```
$tab['1'] = array('1', '2', '3');
$tab['2'] = array('A', 'B', 'C');
```

How can i get this result?

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 B
2 C
3 A
3 B
3 C
```

That is, each element from first array with each element from other arrays.

Comment: PHP does not support the syntax you used.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: On the first look you'd assume a function called `array_product` does this. But on a second look you notice that it actually multiplies the number of the array. Bleh, PHP. Because you have to multiply all elements in an array *that* often!

Comment: Im sorry i was writing fast. I have change code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do a 2-dimensional iteration.

Run through the first array like this

```
foreach ($tab[1] as $number) {...}
```

For each number in the first array, the code in the brackets will be executed. If you want to count each letter for each number, just repeat the same iteration inside:

```
foreach ($tab[1] as $number) {
    foreach ($tab[2] as $letter) {
        print($number.' '.$letter."\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($tab[1] as $num) {
   foreach ($tab[2] as $letter) {
      echo "$num $letter\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (for the fun of it)

```
array_map(function($a, $b) {
             foreach( $b as $e ) {
                 echo "$a $e\n";
             }
          }, 
          $tab['1'], 
          array_fill(0, count($tab['1']), $tab['2']));
```